# How to do paging with a NetSuite Support Case Search?

Tags: web-services, search, web, pagination, netsuite

Our company has a customer center website, done in ASP.NET with C# code behind, that our customers can go to get a variety of different information. One of the pages allows them to look at their support cases. Initially the page only shows open support cases which works properly. Then if they want to, they can click a button that will load all of their support cases, open or closed. For some customers, this can be quite a large number of cases and the NetSuite web service will time out.

To resolve this I am trying to add pagination to this view so that only a page worth of cases is loaded at a time. Does anybody have any experience with paging in NetSuite?

Problems I am having:

1. I can't seem to find a way to quickly return the total count of records to the pager's data source to set up the paging interface.
2. I need a way to return a SearchResult that gets a specific page. I've tried using SearchMore and SearchNext but I can't specify a page. There is no SearchPrevious for just doing Previous and Next pages in the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use searchMoreWithId. http://tellsaqib.github.com/NSPHP-Doc/de/d06/class_net_suite_service.html#a024f8c9b7120c549d72e1d05b6676f6f

Every search returns a searchId. Use this search Id along with page number as parameters for this call.